# error : The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#

Getting this error `The given path's format is not supported.` at this line

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(visit_Path);
```

Where I am doing mistake in below code

```
void Create_VisitDateFolder()
        {
            this.pid = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetPatientID(cmbPatientName.SelectedItem.ToString()));
            String strpath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            String path = strpath + "\\Patients\\Patient_" + pid + "\\";
            string visitdate = db.GetPatient_visitDate(pid);
            this.visitNo = db.GetPatientID_visitNo(pid);
            string visit_Path = path +"visit_" + visitNo + "_" + visitdate+"\\";
            bool IsVisitExist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
            bool IsVisitPath=System.IO.Directory.Exists(visit_Path);
            if (!IsVisitExist)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            if (!IsVisitPath)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(visit_Path);\\error here
            }
        }
```

getting this value for `visit_Path`

```
C:\Users\Monika\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SonoRepo\SonoRepo\bin\Debug\Patients\Patient_16\visit_4_16-10-2013 00:00:00\
```

Comment: `:` in directory name?

Comment: In general, use `Path.Combine` to construct paths instead of `strpath + "\\Patients\\Patient_" + pid + "\\" +"visit_" + visitNo + "_" + visitdate+"\\";`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter can you please show the whole line of code how i can write this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general  always use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to create paths:

```
String strPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
String path = Path.Combine(strPath,"Patients","Patient_" + pid);
string visitdate = db.GetPatient_visitDate(pid);
this.visitNo = db.GetPatientID_visitNo(pid);
string fileName = string.Format("visit_{0}_{1}", visitNo, visitdate);
string visit_Path = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
bool IsVisitExist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
bool IsVisitPath=System.IO.Directory.Exists(visit_Path);
```

To replace invalid characters from a filename you could use this loop:

```
string invalidChars = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
foreach (char c in invalidChars)
{
    visit_Path = visit_Path.Replace(c.ToString(), ""); // or with "."
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can not have `:` in directory name, I suggest you to use this to string to get date in directory name:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh_mm_ss");
```

it will create timestamp like:

> 2013-10-17 05_41_05

additional note:

use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) to make full path, like:

```
var path = Path.Combine(strpath , "Patients", "Patient_" + pid);
```

and last

```
string suffix = "visit_"+visitNo+"_" + visitdate;
var visit_Path = Path.Combine(path, suffix);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't have colons `:` in file paths

Answer (score 3):

You can't use colons (`:`) in a path. You can for example `Replace()` them with dots (`.`).

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add my two cents.
I assigned the path from a text box to string and also adding additional strings, but I forgot to add the .Text to the text box variable.

So instead of

```
strFinalPath = TextBox1.Text + strIntermediatePath + strFilename
```

I wrote

```
strFinalPath = TextBox1 + strIntermediatePath + strFilename
```

So the path became invalid because it contained invalid characters.
I was surprised that c# instead of rejecting the assignment because of type mismatch, assigned invalid value to the final string. 
So look at the path assignment string closely.